# ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper Connection is closed

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, multi-tenant

When I use `DataSourceUtils.getConnection` I got this error `ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper Connection is closed` .
Because the previously created connection has been closed.
And before I use `getConnection()` it did not have the problem but it not good performance to create a new connection for every request.

I'm using multitenancy.

Datasource for write

```
@Primary
@Component
public class InstanceWriteDataSource implements DataSource {

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DataSourceUtils.getConnection(getDataSource());
    }
}
```

Datasource for read

```
@Component
public class InstanceReadDataSource implements DataSource {

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DataSourceUtils.getConnection(getDataSource());
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea about this?
Thank you.